# Finding rectangle of maximum area (optimization/calculus)

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Find the rectangle of maximum area if its vertices are at $(0,0)$, $(x,0)$, $(x,\cos x)$, $(0,\cos x)$.  Assume that $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$.

Attempt at solution: Right now we are on the Bisection Method in Numerical Methods, so I believe this question must be related to a root finding question.
My attempt then is that the area is:
$$\text{Area}= x\cos(x).$$
Taking the derivative using product rule then leads to:
$$-x\sin(x)+\cos(x).$$
Setting this equal to 0 and re-arranging we get:
$$cos(x)=x\sin(x)$$
Dividing by $\cos(x)$ by both sides.
$$1=x\tan(x).$$
Then we have
$$f(x)=\cot(x)-x.$$
Finding the roots of this: I get $x=0.86033.$

Concerns: I'm worried that I'm doing this incorrectly as if I type into wolfram alpha the roots of $-x\sin(x)+\cos(x)$, they give me answers denoting solution over the reals and numerical solutions. I'm not familiar with this distinction.  Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems correct. Regarding Wolfram Alpha, “Solution over the reals” just means a solution in the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (as opposed to the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$). The numerical solutions are just that—the numerical solutions (these are real numbers). In this case there are infinitely many, but you want the one in the range $[0,\pi/2]$, as you have already realized.

Comment: I see thank you!